# How to escape wildcard expansion in a variable in bash?

Tags: bash, wildcard-expansion

How do I escape a wildcard expansion in a variable name?

```
CP="lib/*"
COMMAND="java $VARIABLES -cp $CP SomeClass"
echo $COMMAND
```

Echoing the command always causes wildcard expansion.

Comment: Also on 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102049/how-do-i-escape-the-wildcard-asterisk-character-in-bash/102075#102075

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo "$COMMAND"
```

Using quotes prevents the glob from being expanded.

By the way, see ["I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 1):

["I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Use an array instead.