# Loop over array, preventing wildcard expansion (*)

Tags: bash, variables, wildcard, expansion

I'm trying to figure out what I thought would be a trivial issue in BASH, but I'm having difficulty finding the correct syntax. I want to loop over an array of values, one of them being an asterisk (*), I do not wish to have any wildcard expansion happening during the process.

```
 WHITELIST_DOMAINS="* *.foo.com *.bar.com"
 for domain in $WHITELIST_DOMAINS
 do
    echo "$domain"
 done
```

I have the above, and I'm trying to get the following output:

```
 *
 *.foo.com
 *.bar.com
```

Instead of the above, I get a directory listing on the current directory, followed by *.foo.com and *.bar.com

I know I need some escaping or quoting somewhere.. the early morning haze is still thick on my brain.

I've reviewed these questions:

[How to escape wildcard expansion in a variable in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888764/how-to-escape-wildcard-expansion-in-a-variable-in-bash)

[Stop shell wildcard character expansion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456403/stop-shell-wildcard-character-expansion)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that you want an array, but you wrote a single string that contains the elements with spaces between them. Use an array instead.

```
WHITELIST_DOMAINS=('*' '*.foo.com' '*.bar.com')
```

Always use double quotes around variable substitutions (i.e. `"$foo"`), otherwise the shell splits the the value of the variable into separate words and treats each word as a filename wildcard pattern. The same goes for command substitution: `"$(somecommand)"`. For an array variable, use `"${array[@]}"` to expand to the list of the elements of the array.

```
for domain in "${WHITELIST_DOMAINS[@]}"
 do
    echo "$domain"
 done
```

For more information, see [the bash FAQ about arrays](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005).

Comment: Palm firmly planted on face -- I should have known that I wasn't using an array, thank you for pointing this out so clearly -- and quickly.

Comment: @"otherwise the shell splits the the value of the variable into separate words and treats each word as a filename wildcard pattern" This aspect of shell scripting can be the most difficult to remember when moving between multiple languages. Thank you for refreshing my memory.

Answer (score 2):

You can use array to store them:

```
array=('*' '*.foo.com' '*.bar.com')

for i in "${array[@]}"
do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: This is the same solution as the accepted answer, except that @Giles gave a bit more useful explanation for future users sauntering along via Google. I've accepted his comment over yours for completeness and posterity.