# In Bash, why does VAR="*" when echoed it gives out the list of files in that dir?

Tags: bash, cron

I have been working on setting a cron job programmatically in a Bash script. 
 
In it I have a line like: 
`JOB="00 12 * * * sh dosomething.sh"` 
I noticed if I echoed the var $JOB, it contains the files of the directory?

Is there a way to store the * symbole in a var as a normal character?

Thank you,

Answer (score 5):

You need to quote the variable, for instance when you are echoing it, like so:

```
JOB="00 12 * * * sh dosomething.sh"
echo "$JOB"
```

Reference: [How do I escape the wildcard/asterisk character in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102049/how-do-i-escape-the-wildcard-asterisk-character-in-bash)