# 'find' or 'grep' a filename to match pattern within directories and sub-directories

Tags: search, recursion, grep, filesystems, find

I need to recursively search my filesystem using a 'grep' or 'find' command to match any filename that contains the string "report".

I attempted the command

```
find | grep "report[[:alnum:]]\."
```

and while this was close to the output I wanted, it only gave files that END in 'report.(php/tpl/whatever)'

What is wrong with this command, or what can I use to produce the desired output?

Comment: `find . -name "*report*"` ??

Comment: Perfect mate, thank you. Exactly what I wanted. Any reason behind the syntax using quotes and asterisks in "* report *" ?

Comment: `*` matches anything (even the empty string). Hence, this expression matches all names being like `XXXXreportYYYY`. The usage of quotes is to avoid bash expansion.

Comment: Great, thanks again. Add this as an answer so I can select it as correct.

Comment: @taylordustin This may be biased, but there are still characters that expand in double quotes, i.e. `$`, `!`, etc... So if you're unsure about expansion rules, I would suggest using single quotes when you want bash to treat something as a literal string (in this case you want `find` to process the special characters and `bash` to treat it as a string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following `find` command:

```
find . -name "*report*"
```

`*` matches anything (even the empty string). Hence, this expression matches all names being like `XXXXreportYYYY`.

The usage of quotes is to avoid bash expansion (try `echo *` and see what happens! - [How do I escape the wildcard/asterisk character in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/104023/1983854) may help).