# how do I echo an asterisks to an output

Tags: linux, output, echo

The line in my shell script is

```
OUTPUTMESSAGE="****Warning error $MYERRORNUM ****"
echo $OUTPUTMESSAGE
```

The asterisks are expanded to file names so it looks like

```
file1  file2 file 3 file4 Warning error 404  file1  file2 file 3 file4
```

How do I prevent the `*` expansion in `echo`?

Comment: Is valid for bash, try it: http://www.compileonline.com/execute_bash_online.php

Comment: The bash escape character is ``\`` backslash, not `/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote the variable name not only in assignment, but also in your `echo` command:

```
OUTPUTMESSAGE="****Warning error $MYERRORNUM ****"
echo "$OUTPUTMESSAGE"
```

More information can be found in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102049/how-do-i-escape-the-wildcard-asterisk-character-in-bash).