# Casting a string to not allow for interpolation within a function in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

I'm looking for some way to print an asterisk in a string passed to a program in shell. These problems are similar but I haven't been able to make any of the solutions work in my case: [how do I echo an asterisks to an output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26833786/how-do-i-echo-an-asterisks-to-an-output), [Printing asterisk (*) in bash shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277037/printing-asterisk-in-bash-shell), [How do I escape the wildcard/asterisk character in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102049/how-do-i-escape-the-wildcard-asterisk-character-in-bash).

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# First function
function()
{
typeset -r str=$1
typeset -i N=$2
typeset -i i=0
while [[ $i -lt $N ]];
do
    echo $str| sed "s/<token>/$i/g"
    (( i+=1 ))
done
}

# 'main' function
doStuff()
{
foo.pl << EOF

some words $(function "input string with asterisk * and some <token> after it" 123)
some more words

EOF
    [ $? -eq 0 ] || logerror "Function 'doStuff' failed."
}

doStuff

exit 0
```

When running the skript, the asterisk is substituted with the results of `echo *`.
To fix this I have tried declaring `ASTERISK='*'` and substituting it in, as well as simply altering the function call to `$(function "input string with asterisk "'*'" and some <token> after it" 123)`, but neither did the trick.

I suspect the problem is the `echo` statement inside `function`, but am not quite sure how to solve it, so my question would be if there is any way to cast `str` in `function` to not allow for interpolation once it is within `function`?

Comment: `set -o noglob`?

Comment: Quote your parameter expansions, and use shellcheck.net.

Comment: @arco444 that did the trick, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [arco444](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3115685/arco444)'s suggestion, using `set -o noglob` before the `sed` in `function` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can surround the variable expansion with `""` to avoid the glob.

```
echo "$str" | ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, forgot to mention it in the question, I have done that, but it did not work