# How to escape special character in curl post

Tags: post, curl, encoding, escaping, splunk

How do I escape these kinds of special character in curl. The below is passed in the query part. I am trying to query splunk data and this is reg expression with rex command. Without the below characters it works fine. But I need this to be part of the query.

(?i)^(?:[^-]*-){}\s+\d+

I tried giving -g to stop globbing. But that doesn't work. Is there any simpler way to do this. I am passing --data urlencode in curl so encoding is automatically taken care.

Comment: See if the help in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102049/how-do-i-escape-the-wildcard-asterisk-character-in-bash will help you. Since I'm suspecting this is a shell problem, and not a curl problem.

Comment: Can you try adding your curl script to a .sh file, and running it?

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered the exact same problem statement. Splunk was having an issue with my regex when it contained `[` or `]` characters. I was also using curl, and I was sending my search query with curl's `-d`  parameter for post data. I tried several variations of encoding of the brackets (escaping them, percent-encoding them, etc.), but to no avail.

The solution in my case was to use the `--data-urlencode` parameter instead of the `--data` parameter.

From the curl help:

```
 $ curl --help | grep "\-\-data"  
  -d/--data <data>   HTTP POST data (H)
     --data-ascii <data>  HTTP POST ASCII data (H)
     --data-binary <data> HTTP POST binary data (H)
     --data-urlencode <name=data/name@filename> HTTP POST data url encoded (H)
```

Comment: In my curl version 7.68 this is `--data-urlencode`, not `--data-url-encode`

Comment: Oops had the right parameter in the curl output but not in my answer. Fixed it! Thanks @dzieciou