# Issues with c shell escape character for *

Tags: shell, csh

So first and foremost, this is homework.  Just struggling with something that I can't find out too much information about through google.

Question is print the product of the integers from 1 through the number entered.

So if we input 4, we give 24 (1*2*3*4) as the output.

My question is, I can't figure out how to escape the * character to concatenate it to my string.  I have this working on bourne shell, but keep running into this issue in c shell.

```
@ temp = 1
@ ans = 1
while ( $temp <= $number )
    @ ans = ( $ans * $temp )
    @ temp = ( $temp + 1 )
end
set ans = "$ans ("
@ count = 1
while ( $count <= $number )
    set ans = "$ans$count"
    @ count = ( $count + 1 )
    if ( $count <= $number ) then
        set ans = "$ans*"
    endif
end
set ans = "$ans)"
echo $ans
```

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
set star = "*"
set ans = "$ans$star"
```

**Edit** 
[How do I escape the wildcard/asterisk character in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102049/how-do-i-escape-the-wildcard-asterisk-character-in-bash) Quotes needed for your echo:

```
echo "$ans"
```

Comment: Thought about this.  Actually tried that already before posting.  I still get a echo:No match. when trying to echo out ans.

Comment: You're linking to a bash question. This is about csh.

Answer (score 1):

When echoing variables, use double quotes around the variable (`echo "$ans"`) to avoid having the shell expand metacharacters in the variable's value:

(Script file: `prod.csh`):

```
#!/bin/tcsh

@ number = 6
@ temp = 1
@ ans = 1
while ( $temp <= $number )
    @ ans = ( $ans * $temp )
    @ temp = ( $temp + 1 )
end
set ans = "$ans ("
@ count = 1
while ( $count <= $number )
    set ans = "$ans$count"
    @ count = ( $count + 1 )
    if ( $count <= $number ) then
        set ans = "$ans*"
    endif
end
set ans = "$ans)"
echo "$ans"
```

Example run:

```
$ tcsh prod.csh
720 (1*2*3*4*5*6)
$
```

Comment: You can also use `set noglob` by the way, which is sometimes useful as adding quotes can get tricky in some situations.