# Why does bash documentation suggest quoting wildcard characters?

Tags: linux, bash, wildcard

In several manuals (including the official GNU/Linux Command-Line Tools [tldp.org](http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm)) is recommended to use single (or double quotes) to avoid bash to interpret wildcards or regex symbols like caret (^) and dollar ($).

But in some examples that's not necessary to use single/double quotes. For instance:

(1)

```
$ touch 'fo*'
```

and

```
$ touch fo*
```

creates the same file `fo*` in both command line forms.

(2)

```
$ grep '^foo' file.txt
```

and

```
$ grep ^foo file.txt
```

both search for `foo` as a string in beginning of the lines of file.txt.

Why manuals recommend to use single/double quotes to avoid bash interpretation if bash in fact does not interpret some wildcards and regex symbols in first place?

Comment: ... Because Murphy's Law is a thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I escape the wildcard/asterisk character in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102049/how-do-i-escape-the-wildcard-asterisk-character-in-bash)

Comment: The 2nd highest answer above has a good synopsis of why.

Comment: It interprets them **when something matches**. So if you have a `foobar`, then `touch fo*` will expand to that. It's even more fun (read: unpredictable and convoluted) if you have non-default shell options set.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/104023/14122 is definitely a great answer; unfortunately, while the answer is on-point, I'm not certain that that's also true for the question itself.

Comment: BTW, glob patterns are not regular expressions; the regex tag is completely off-topic here.

Comment: Quoting `^foo` is not strictly necesssary; `^` is special in regular expressions, but not in glob patterns. Still, it's easier to quote it than to prove to yourself that you don't need to (as I write this I'm not even 100% certain myself).

Comment: @KeithThompson, quite -- there's enough potential for some shell to implement a new `extglob` (or history-expansion) option that even if you don't need to quote `^` today, you might need to quote it tomorrow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there is a file named `foo` in the current directory, then `touch 'fo*'` touches `fo*`, but `touch fo*` would expand to `touch foo` and touch that instead.

If the `nullglob` option is set and no file name matching `fo*` exists, `touch fo*` would expand to just `touch` and complain about the missing operand.

If the `failglob` option is set and no file name matching `fo*` exists, `touch fo*` would immediately cause an error.

Comment: `failglob` is an important option that is often overlooked in these types of questions. I didn't fully appreciate this until I started using `zsh`, where the `failglob` behavior is the default, and I needed to start quoting URLs with `?` in them when running `curl`.

Answer (score 2):

Bash attempts to expand all wildcards, as seen with `failglob` enabled.

```
(shopt -s failglob; compgen -G 'f*' || : f*; })
```

```
bash: no match: f*
```

Put literally, this code creates a subshell and enables the `failglob` option. Then it runs the `compgen` builtin which accepts literal `'f*'` and attempts to generate completions. If this fails, the conditional construct `||` falls back to the no-op command expression `: f*` which prompts bash to attempt expanding the pattern `f*`.

When this point in the code is reached, with compgen having established that no files matching the glob are present, filename expansion inevitably fails, resulting in a `no match` error.

Comment: ...I might also have the example create, and `cd` into, an empty directory, just to be sure that `f*` doesn't expand to something. That, or use a longer and thus less-likely-to-collide name (ie `foo-nonexistent*`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy good idea. I went with the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937407/test-whether-a-glob-has-any-matches-in-bash as a necessary precondtion.