# how to use * in script so it retains special meaning

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a line in my script as below:

`ls -l $In_File_Path$In_File_NAME.*.txt >> vendor_file_list.dat`

When I run this from the linux command prompt it works and populates the vendor_file_list.dat with file name; but in a script it fails stating no file or directory found.

Can anybody please help?

Comment: Check if your working directory in the script is the same. (Run `pwd` from the prompt and from the script.)

Comment: @KirillBulygin I am giving full path of file while doing ls -l

Comment: Can you add an echo statement and check what is the value for "$In_File_Path$In_File_NAME.*.txt" in your script.

Comment: @NishuTayal /usr/local/distrack/gartrack/ftp/GTS.*.txt: No such file or directory
GTSVendorLoad.sh[44]: syntax error at line 64 : `else' unexpected
dcsdb01 /usr/local/distrack/gartrack/external >ls -l /usr/local/distrack/gartrack/ftp/GTS.*.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 distrack payroll      157 Oct  3 01:34 /usr/local/distrack/gartrack/ftp/GTS.20181003063954.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 distrack payroll      336 Oct  3 03:31 /usr/local/distrack/gartrack/ftp/GTS.20181003084007.txt

Comment: there's a syntax error in your script, so that needs to be corrected first - can you post up the whole script, or at least the major control structures in/around the ls command?

Comment: `/usr/local/distrack/gartrack/ftp/GTS.*.txt: No such file or directory` means that there are no files matching that pattern.  The `*` is retained if `bash` does not find files matching the pattern.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I escape the wildcard/asterisk character in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102049/how-do-i-escape-the-wildcard-asterisk-character-in-bash)

Comment: @phuzi I don't think that's the actual problem here; seems like the OP actually wants the wildcard to be expanded (even though the title says completely something else).

Comment: How are `In_File_Path` and `In_File_NAME` being set?

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

1. As  Kirill says in the comments, make sure you are executing the script in the directory you want to
2. There are 2 shell variables in your ls command `$In_File_Path` and `$In_File_NAME`, so you need to make sure these are defined correctly in your script (they will be case-sensitive)

Comment: /usr/local/distrack/gartrack/ftp/GTS.*.txt: No such file or directory
GTSVendorLoad.sh[44]: syntax error at line 64 : `else' unexpected
dcsdb01 /usr/local/distrack/gartrack/external >ls -l /usr/local/distrack/gartrack/ftp/GTS.*.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 distrack payroll      157 Oct  3 01:34 /usr/local/distrack/gartrack/ftp/GTS.20181003063954.txt

Comment: Such error messages would help us much more if we could see the code they refer to (`syntax error at line 64`, etc.).