# issues with filter wildcards on gcloud sdk (ubuntu)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

I'm attempting to parse external IP addresses of GCP compute instances in an instance group, then separate them with commas, to inject into a configuration file for a software.

I've created a command that does this successfully on my Mac (10.14.6):

```
gcloud compute instances list --filter="name :(name-of-instance*)" \
--format="get(networkInterfaces[0].accessConfigs[0].natIP)" \
| tr '\n' ',' | sed s/.$//
```

which immediately outputs a list:
`x.x.x.x,y.y.y.y,z.z.z.z`

this command is then put into a bash script that will be running on a compute instance (running Ubuntu 1604LTS).
however, **when I try on a test instance (Ubuntu 1604LTS), the previous command with the wildcard `*` does not output anything**.

I've tested this by removing the wildcard and specifying the full name of one of the instances, and it does output the external IP of that instance correctly:

```
gcloud compute instances list --filter="name :(name-of-instance-full)" \
--format="get(networkInterfaces[0].accessConfigs[0].natIP)" \
| tr '\n' ',' | sed s/.$//
```

I've tried with several [Filter Expressions](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters) including `name : (instanceName*)`, `name ~ ^instanceName*`, `name = instanceName*` (wildcards are not permitted for the `=` expression so it fails everywhere).

I cannot tell if this is a bug in gcloud sdk or if I'm missing something about how filters work on GCP compute instances.

expected result on Ubuntu1604LTS when using wildcard:
`x.x.x.x,y.y.y.y,z.z.z.z` (same as on Mac)

actual result when using wildcard:

Comment: Maybe try and escape the asterisk ... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102049/how-do-i-escape-the-wildcard-asterisk-character-in-bash

Answer (score 4):

Agreed with [amanda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9487415/amanda)'s answer but as per gcp [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters#Operator-Terms) **:(colon)** support has been deprecated and will be dropped shortly.

So Instead as per the example [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gcloud-compute/tips#fetching-examples-list) below should work:

```
gcloud compute instances list --filter="name~instance-name" \
--format="get(networkInterfaces[0].accessConfigs[0].natIP)" \
| tr '\n' ',' | sed s/.$//
```

Answer (score 1):

turns out the spaces that were between the key pair and the parentheses needed to be removed to make this work in Ubuntu:

```
gcloud compute instances list --filter="name:instance-name*" \
--format="get(networkInterfaces[0].accessConfigs[0].natIP)" \
| tr '\n' ',' | sed s/.$//
```